# android keyboard opening and closing is not smooth

Tags: android, keyboard

In my application I need keyboard to open a little bit smooth. How can I handle this?

Comment: what have you tried ? what are your difficulties ? or do you just expect SO to provide you with ready made code ?

Comment: I didn't tried anything because I didn't find any way, I need some link, some suggestion , code will be more effective.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the opening of the keyboard is an Android-handled operation, so there's no way that you can alter how smoothly it opens. I may be wrong though

Comment: Well if there is, in all fairness I would have expected them to have answered by now, which probably means that I was correct in what I said